# d3 barplot - why are labels not showing ?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I drew a bar plot with D3. 
I want to have the x axis values on the bottom and the y values on the bar it self.

for some odd reason the labels are not showing.

would appreciate any one who could take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/E89tQ/).

the relevant section in at the end

```
// why isnt this showing ??? <-------------------------- right here
// price tags on the bars
svg.selectAll("text")
 .data(y)
 .enter()
 .append("text")
 .text(function(d ,i) { return Math.round(y[i]).toLocaleString() ;}) 
 .attr("y" , function(d) { return height - yscale(d);})
 .attr("x" , function(d, i) { return i * (bar_width + spacing) + bar_width / 4})
 .classed("analysis-result-label" , true);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The labels aren't showing because of the way you're selecting and matching data. Each time you're calling `.data()`, D3 matches the contents of the selection you've made in the step before to the data you pass as an argument. For the second set of labels, you're selecting `text` elements. This selection will contain the elements you've just added before. Each of the data items will have a matching DOM element and therefore, the `.enter()` selection will be empty. Hence nothing is added.

The easiest way to avoid this issue is to use the classes you're already assigning to the `text` elements in the selection. That is,

```
svg.selectAll("text")
```

would become

```
svg.selectAll("text.analysis-result-label")
```

This means that the second selection will be empty as there are `text` elements, but not of that particular class, and the rest of the code will work as expected.

Complete jsfiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/E89tQ/1/).

Comment: Thanks. I got it. it took me a while to get the hang of that enter() function... one step at a time.